# Help Rounding division

Tags: c#, .net, math

I need the end result to be a whole number.  If the division is a whole number fine but if it ends up with a decimal, I need to round up (midpoint).

Example if the division is 85.5, round up and result should be 86
If the division is 85.4, it would naturally round down ...basic rounding rules
If it's a whole number 85, then we're all good but should I store the result regardless of these 3 situations as type double?

```
double totalFoundPercent = Math.Round(
        (double) (totalNumbersDeleted / (totalNumbers - totalNumbersApproved)), 
                  MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

This is giving me an error of:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
>   'System.Math.Round(double, System.MidpointRounding)'  and
>   'System.Math.Round(decimal, System.MidpointRounding)'

So I am not sure if this should be stored as a type double in the end or not plus the problem with the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have rounded a number, you have the choice of storing it as a `integer` or `long` as appropriate. You could choose to store it as a floating point type such as `float` or `double` but as you know it has no fractional part it would probably be clearer to a reader to see it represented as an integral type.

One thing to bear in mind is that floating point numbers are able to imprecisely store very large numbers which may not fit into a regular `int` or even `long` type. The biggest long is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` whereas the biggest `double` is `1.7976931348623157 × 10³⁰⁸`.

The error, however is confusing as it should patently be calling the `double` overload: there is no implicit conversion between `double` and `decimal` and your cast makes the type very clear. Are you sure you are getting this error with the exact code you have in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the second parameter. Based on your description, you shouldn't need it.

```
double totalFoundPercent = Math.Round((double) (totalNumbersDeleted / (totalNumbers - totalNumbersApproved)));
```

Comment: OP wants to round up. Without the second parameter it will round down for even numbers.

Comment: "OP wants to round up." That's not how I read it. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Read the first sentence of the question: "I need to round up". He wants to round up for numbers where the fractional part is >= .5 and down for < .5. I believe from that he would not expect banker's rounding behaviour.